# Thymleaf 3, attoparser, CDATA and HTML templating with script tag

Tags: html, templates, thymeleaf

I struggled with Spring Boot 1.3.5 which has dependency on old Thymeleaf 2.x series by trying to pass HTML template inside `script` tag:

```
<script type="text/template" id="catTmpl">
  <![CDATA[
  <b><%=name%></b>
  ]]>
</script>
```

which resulted in error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

and after some manipulation it was properly passed but rendered with CDATA wrapping, that broke JS templating (`undescore.js` in my case):

```
_.template($("#catTmpl").html())
```

I came across some blog and found that Thymleaf 3 uses different parser. Checked:

```
$ gradle dependencies
|    |    +--- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.0.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.attoparser:attoparser:2.0.4.RELEASE
```

That parser assumes that `script` contain CDATA and above code works fine without CDATA.

What is `attoparser`?

Is Thymeleaf 3 ready to pass HTML templates via `script` (or HTML 5 `template`) tag without CDATA bullshit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attoparser` is http://www.attoparser.org/ From project home page:

- To be easy to use. Few lines of code needed. And no more parser library hell worrying about your JDK's parser API versions.
- To be fast. As fast as the fastest standard parsers. And in many scenarios, faster.
- To offer a powerful interface. Consider well-formedness optional, line + column location, ability to reconstruct the original document, etc.
- To simplify your parsing experience. By removing the need to worry about validation or entity resolution —both unneeded in many cases.

As written in mail list `attoparser` was designed to work with Thymeleaf.

It is able to parse HTML (so no need to close `<p>`), but [as say this blog post](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/blog/broadleaf-commerce-upgrade-to-thymeleaf-3) parser accept `<div/>` which is invalid HTML 5. Thymeleaf 2 also accept this but produced valid `<div></div>`, Thymeleaf 3 don't. Be careful!

According to [bug Modify the way  is considered CDATA #9](https://github.com/attoparser/attoparser/issues/9) `attoparser` interprets `script` body as CDATA only for:

> All these alternatives should not be considered CDATA by default (unless they are explicitly enclosed in a CDATA section), so it should be a good idea to only consider the contents of  a CDATA in the following situations regarding type:
>
> - No type
> - type is one of: javascript, ecmascript, text/javascript, text/ecmascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript